# Iterate over each message in JavaScript for loop?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

When I click on ‘Unread’
Then the Message will disappear from my list of Messages. In addition to this I want to iterate over each message in a for loop so they get removed each time I click Unread. I am trying to do a JavaScript remove function please see below, how will I iterate through each message?

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="settings-pills">
@{
if (Model.Messages.Count > 0)
{
var messageCounter = 0;
foreach (var message in Model.Messages)
{
messageCounter++;
if (messageCounter <= 5)
{
<div class="alert alert-default alert-dismissible" role="alert" style="background: rgb(233, 233, 233);">

<button class="close" aria-label="Close" type="button" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
```

Unread

```
<p class="small"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> Unread</p></div>

<p class="small"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> @message.CreatedOn.ToString("dd MMM yyyy")</p>

<p class="small" style="font-weight: bold;"><i class="fa fa-info" aria-hidden="true"></i> Claim ref. @message.CaseNumber</p>

<p>@message.Message <a href="@Url.Action("Details","Enquiry" , new { id = @message.EnquityId })">More.</a></p>

</div>
}
else
{
<div class="alert alert-default alert-dismissible  message-More" role="alert" style="display:none;background: rgb(233, 233, 233);">

<button class="close" aria-label="Close" type="button" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>

<p class="small"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> @message.CreatedOn.ToString("dd MMM yyyy")</p>

<p class="small" style="font-weight: bold;"><i class="fa fa-info" aria-hidden="true"></i> Claim ref. @message.CaseNumber</p>

<p>@message.Message <a href="@Url.Action("Details","Enquiry", new { id = @message.EnquityId })">More.</a></p>
</div>
```

JavaScript which I think needs to iterate over each message.

```
    $(".unreadmessage").click(function () {
        var messageId=$(this).data("id");

        $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: You need to add a class of "message" or something to each message. Then use the jQuery selector and the .each() function.

Comment: Could you edit the code for me please @James

Comment: I added an answer

Comment: That doesnt remove each message 1 by 1

Comment: Did you run the JsBin? It does remove them one by one

Comment: Yes I did it works on JsBin but no on my code

Comment: @James this is just removing the unread line not the message

Comment: what element is left after the line is removed?

Comment: basically the whole message now I change the code so each message gets an ID please see above. @James

Comment: you don't have your elements properly indented so it's tough to see which element is the outer-most element or container for your unread message. Which element provides the "container" for the unread messgae? Is it the <div> with the alert class?

Comment: this gives ID to each message <div id="Unreadmessage" class="unreadmessage" data-messageid="@message.Id">
 <p class="small"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> Unread</p></div>

Comment: we don't want to use the ID of unreadMessage. We want all of our unreadMessages to have a class of that. Not an ID. When you use the code I gave you to remove it, is the <div> with the class of unreadmessage still there?

Comment: I am unable to give a class to each message because the message goes through a loop theretofore i added a ID

Comment: are you just trying to delete the <p> tag that the message is wrapped in?

Comment: I am trying to delete the whole message from the view each time they click unread on a message

Comment: What is considered "the whole message?" Just the <p> tag or the <div> tag with the class of "alert alert-default alert-dismissible"

Comment: Messages in the for loop

Comment: you need to tell me what element creates the message. What elements do you want to delete?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to simply delete all .alert-dismissible. Perform this

```
$(".alert-dismissible").each(function(){
       $(this).remove();
}
```

Comment: I need to add a class of message to each message how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

After reading the question again, I *think* I have an idea of what you are struggling with. You just want to remove the unread message from the list after the user reads it. That's pretty simple. Do this:

```
$(".UnreadMessage").click(function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

**I made a quick JSBin to help out** http://jsbin.com/leneciluyu/edit?html,js,output